# Margins drastically different in Safari than Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, safari

I just jumped into a project that was about 70% finished. The home page html5 video section and general layout of home page look perfect on Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari, giant random margins appear above and below the html5 video header. I realized that adding `width:100%;` and `height:100%;` are causing the added margins.

[Please take a look](http://2016.times10.net/) and compare them on each browser.

I've tried adding `display:block` to the video container as well as changing `margin` to `padding`.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took out `width:100%` and `height:100%` and added `min-width:100%` and it did the trick.